# Diameter of circle need to drill 40 holes around it 1cm apart??

Tags: geometry

So I need to drill 40 holes in a circular pattern each 1cm (chord?) apart from each other. What is the equation to figure out the diameter, radius or circumference of the circle that I need? If I can figure that, then I can easily make my template and use a compass to mark out my 40 pilot holes. I feel like this should be an easy equation, but I must be missing something...

Comment: How big are the forty holes? If they are a meter across, you probably need a larger circle than if they are millimeter across...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Circumradius

Comment: @Aganju — they’re going to be small, and it doesn’t really matter because I just want the centerpoints to be 1cm apart.

Comment: @amd — thank you, so if I understand that equation mine is... R = 1cm / 2sin (pi / 40)?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Having the centers 1cm apart is a bit different from having the holes be 1cm apart. We’re picky about that sort of thing here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

40 segments around the circle is enough to ignore the error compared to infinity, so you can just use:

$$\pi * d = 40 * 1 cm$$

which gives you $d = 40 cm / \pi = \sim12.7 cm$ ( or $r = d / 2 = \sim6.4 cm$)